# How to compile/eval a Scala expression at runtime?

Tags: scala

New to Scala and looking for pointers to an idiomatic solution, if there is one.

I'd like to have arbitrary user-supplied Scala functions (which are allowed to reference functions/classes I have defined in my code) applied to some data.

For example: I have `foo(s: String): String` and `bar(s: String): String` functions defined in my `myprog.scala`.  The user runs my program like this:

```
$ scala myprog data.txt --func='(s: Str) => foo(bar(s)).reverse'
```

This would run line by line through the data file and emit the result of applying the user-specified function to that line.

For extra points, can I ensure that there are no side-effects in the user-defined function?  If not, can I restrict the function to use *only* a restricted subset of functions (which I can assure to be safe)?

Comment: I'd look at how the lambdabot on freenode is written, your problems sounds similar.

Answer (score 4):

@kenjiyoshida has a nice [gist](https://gist.github.com/xuwei-k/9ba39fe22f120cb098f4) that shows how to eval Scala code. Note that when using `Eval` from that gist, not specifying a return value will result in a runtime failure when Scala defaults to inferring `Nothing`.

```
scala> Eval("println(\"Hello\")")
Hello
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
  ... 42 elided
```

vs

```
scala> Eval[Unit]("println(\"Hello\")")
Hello
```

It nicely handles whatever's in scope as well.

```
 object Thing {
   val thing: Int = 5
 }

 object Eval {

   def apply[A](string: String): A = {
     val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
     val tree = toolbox.parse(string)
     toolbox.eval(tree).asInstanceOf[A]
   }

   def fromFile[A](file: File): A =
     apply(scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).mkString(""))

   def fromFileName[A](file: String): A =
     fromFile(new File(file))

 }

 object Thing2 {
   val thing2 = Eval[Int]("Thing.thing") // 5
 }
```

Twitter's [`util`](https://github.com/twitter/util) package used to have `util-eval`, but that seems to have been deprecated now (and also triggers a compiler bug when compiled).

As for the second part of your question, the answer seems to be no. Even if you disable default `Predef` and imports yourself, a user can always get to those functions with the fully qualified package name. You could perhaps use Scala's `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox` to first parse your string and then compare against a whitelist, before passing to `eval`, but at that point things could get pretty hairy since you'll be manually writing code to sanitize the Scala AST (or at the very least reject dangerous input). It definitely doesn't seem to be an "idiomatic solution."

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using the standard Java JSR 223 Scripting Engine

see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-874

(also mentions using scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter but not sure this is still available)

```scala
import javax.script.*;
ScriptEngine e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");
e.getContext().setAttribute("label", new Integer(4), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
try {
    engine.eval("println(2+label)");
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```