# Scala create method at run time from a string and invoke it

Tags: scala, reflection

Is there any way I can create a method in scala from a string and then invoke it? For example

```
val code = "(a: String, b:String) => {a+b}"
```

I would like to know if there is any way to instantiate the method and invoke it?

I have explored toolbox and twitter util eval both of them requires me to compile and instantiate the method 
`asInstanceOf[(String, String) => Option[Any]]`

To do this I need to know the arguments and their types, I am looking for way in which I don't need to know the argument types before hand.

Comment: Then maybe use `(Any, Any) => Nothing`

Comment: I also don't know the number of arguments as the code comes from else where.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757916/how-to-compile-eval-a-scala-expression-at-runtime

Comment: So how are you planning to call it? Can you give more context?

Comment: You need to give it a type in order to call it in Scala. You can use `Any => Any`, if you don't want to restrict things.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do such unsafe thing

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for Python? :)

Comment: The reason why I want to do this, I want to supply this method to spark UDF registration. But the point I want to understand is, is there any way I can infer the type information from the method itself ? Or it is mandatory that I should always let the compiler know that the object I am going to load in the runtime will be of X type so to avoid run time issues?

Comment: I am ok to use Any as my type for arguments and return type but how to tell compiler that I might as well have variable number of arguments which I don't know at the compile time?

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is your own expression language and a parser of that language in your scala app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at twitter util eval api

```
import com.twitter.util.Eval 
val func = new Eval().apply[(String, String)=>String]("(a: String, b:String) => a+b")



scala> func("ab", "cd")
res1: String = abcd
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use the function created like this as an UDF in spark it fails with java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

Comment: Not sure how you wrote the code, actually below sample code seems working at my spark local mode:
`
rdd.mapPartitions{
  x =>
    import com.twitter.util.Eval
    val func = new Eval().apply[(String, String)=>String]("(a: String, b:String) => a+b")
    x.map(
      y =>
    func(y.toString, y.toString)
  )

}
`

Comment: val func = new Eval().apply[(String, String)=>String]("(a: String, b:String) => a+b") sparkSession.sqlContext.udf.register("concatUDF", func)
    val sqlDF2 = sparkSession.sql("SELECT concatUDF(name, name) as welcome FROM employee")
    sqlDF2.show()

Comment: It throws up an exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

Comment: this happens only when I register udf from dynamically compiled function such as the example given by you.

Comment: I guess we can't use udf in that way, it is probably because the func is not serialisable. I would suggest you use the built-in concat udf in HIVE directly for this case.

Comment: But i need to have custom udfs let's say field check on schema less data etc. Is there any way we can get this working? Can't we wrap this function in a class and compile it on the fly?